# Get custom field value from specific post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I use this code in functions.php file:

```
function get_custom_field_value($szKey, $bPrint = false) {
global $post;
$szValue = get_post_meta($post->ID, $szKey, true);
if ( $bPrint == false ) return $szValue; else echo $szValue;}
```

and this one in my HTML to reference it when I need to get a custom field:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){
    get_custom_field_value('now_location', true);} ?>
```

But this works only when I use it inside a post because it takes current post's field value.

How do I get a field value (or several for that matter) from one exact post?
I guess it has something to do with post's ID but I don't know what to change/add to the code.

Comment: What are you using? What is $post, cus it's not the same as $_POST

Comment: I just copied the code from [here](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-easily-get-the-value-of-a-custom-field).
As I said, it works fine when I use it inside a post but it doesn't when I want to get specific field value from specific post and display the value in a separate `div`.

Comment: Why not give post ID as an argument, at least makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @DamienPirsy and @Niels `$post` is a global wordpress variable...

Comment: If I change the existing function and add the post ID, won't that affect all my references in HTML to this function? Then all the references will take field value from that one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @janw suggests It is good to pass the post id as an argument in order to get custom fields for a particular post.

```
function get_custom_field_value($szKey,$postId, $bPrint = false) {
$szValue = get_post_meta($postId, $szKey, true);
if ( $bPrint == false ) return $szValue; else echo $szValue;}
```

Comment: Do I add it as a new function, alongside the existing one?
If yes, what PHP code should I use when referencing that function in HTML? And do I just add my post ID like this: `... get_custom_field_value($szKey,$23, $bPrint = false)...`

Comment: if the post id is 23 and you are going to use the function in my comment, here is the code get_custom_field_value($szKey,23, $bPrint = false);

Comment: Works great with a small modification. I had to write `get_custom_field_value($szKey,23, true);` when referencing the function.
Why is there `$bPrint = false`?
Now I have a problem when referencing this function inside a post, it doesn't show it at all.

Comment: This is what I want to achieve: 1. get a value (for example `my_location`) from a one specific post and show it in a part of my header and 2. get a different value (for example `product_price`) from within any post to show inside that same post. I hope it's clear now. Can I use your function for both things or do I need two different ones? If i need just this one, what should be my HTML code for getting a value from within a post and show it in that post?

Comment: Sorry for the "$bPrint = false". You have to get the post id and pass it to the function. Usually for a single post page you can use $post->ID and if you use some other custom loops you have to use that object instead of post. I hope this will solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: This is my complete code in functions: `function get_custom_field_value($szKey,$postId, $bPrint = false) {global $post;
$szValue = get_post_meta($postId, $szKey, true);
if ( $bPrint == false ) return $szValue; else echo $szValue;}`
I use this to get a value from specific post: `<?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){get_custom_field_value('value_name',23, true);} ?>` and this is the code I use within a post: `<?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){get_custom_field_value('other_value_name',$post->ID, true);} ?>`.
Thank you for your help, it all works great now!

Comment: Just one more question. What is `$bPrint`?

Comment: I used it because it is in your script. The use of this $bPrint is if you set it to true then it displays on the page. If you set to false it just returns the value and you can get it in a variable and use it for any other purpose. Hope this helps.

Comment: Displays what on the page if set to `true`? I don't intend to use it, just interested in what it does.

Comment: True = Displays the custom field value of the $szKey. False = Just return the custom field value of the $szKey.